# List custom post type tags name and slug

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

I have custom post type archive template where I list custom post type 'demos' tag cloud for filtering as follows:

```
<?php query_posts(array( 'post_type'=> 'demos' ));
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$custom_post_tags = get_the_tags();
if ( $custom_post_tags ) {
    foreach( $custom_post_tags as $tag ) {
        $tags_arr[] = $tag -> name;
    }
}
endwhile; endif;
if( $tags_arr ) {
    $uniq_tags_arr = array_unique( $tags_arr );
    foreach( $uniq_tags_arr as $tag ) {
    // LIST ALL THE TAGS FOR DESIRED POST TYPE
    $sanitizeTag =  sanitize_title($tag);
    // would like to use slug instead of sanitize_title();
    echo '<button type="button" class="control control-topic" data-toggle=".' . $sanitizeTag. '"><span class="control-ellipse"></span>' .$tag. '</button>'; 
    }
}
wp_reset_query()
?>
```

**Issue:**
instead of sanitizeTag i would like to use the slug from tag. `$sanitizeTag = $term -> slug;` does not work as expected. How could I achieve this?